# Stability results for general linear stochastic ODE

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, stability

I am interested in the following time-invariant multivariate SDE:
\begin{equation}
dx_i = \sum_{j} a_{ij} x_j\,dt + \sum_{j,k} b_{ijk} x_k \, dW_j
\end{equation}
Despite its simplicity the general solution to SDEs of this form seems elusive (see e.g. [Solution of multivariate Geometric Brownian Motion?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285251/solution-of-multivariate-geometric-brownian-motion) and [General solution to system of stochastic linear differential equations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224660/general-solution-to-system-of-stochastic-linear-differential-equations)). I have a more limited question: what are the criteria under which solutions of this SDE converge almost surely to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing $y = x/|x|$ and $r = \log |x|$ it is not difficult to see that $y$ solves an autonomous SDE and there exists a function $F$ such that $r(t) = r(0) + \int_0^t F(y(s))\ ds$. Since $y$ takes values in the sphere it admits an invariant measure $\mu$ which, under rather weak non-degeneracy assumptions on $A$ and $B$, is unique. The sharp criterion then is whether $\int F(y)\mu(dy)$ is strictly negative or not.

In general there is no closed form expression for $\mu$, but one can of course play around with Lyapunov functions to get sufficient conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Since interested in convergence to zero or $x_{*}$, one approach is phrasing it as a gradient descent SDE [An SDE perspective on stochastic convex optimization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.02750.pdf) i.e. writing it as a convex function $f$ with

$$\partial_{i}f(x)=-\sum_{j}a_{ij}x_{j}$$

and so if we let $$f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}a_{ij}x_{j}x_{i}=-\frac{1}{2}x^{T}Ax,$$ we need the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ to be negative definite and symmetric. For the volatility coefficient they needed bounded and Lipschitz.

Here are some other tools to help you study the growth of the process. The most comprehensive tool is Feller's test (Shreve-Karatzas theorem 5.29).
Secondly, one can also use Lyapunov functions as done in ["Stochastic Stability of Differential Equations"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-23280-0). Also see "Solutions of Stochastic Differential Equations obeying the Law of the Iterated Logarithm, with Applications to Financial Markets∗".

Thirdly, if one is looking for invariant measures, you can use the stationary Fokker-Plank eg. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683775/invariant-measures-for-stochastic-processes and ["Long-time dynamics
of stochastic differential equations"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.12998.pdf).

Comment: I don't think that A need be negative definite for convergence to zero-- this is manifestly not required in the one dimensional case (geometric brownian motion), where the correct condition is A-B^2/2 < 0.

Comment: I didn't say it is necessary, just sufficient based on the linked article in order to get a convex function.